# Adding columns to dataframe that depends on a existing column and its qcut bin values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like below.
dataframe1 =

```
Ind ID  T1  T2  T3  T4  T5
0   Q1  100 121 43  56  78
1   Q2  23  43  56  76  87
2   Q3  345 56  76  78  98
3   Q4  21  32  34  45  56
4   Q5  45  654 567 78  90
5   Q6  123 32  45  56  67
6   Q7  23  24  25  26  27
7   Q8  32  33  34  35  36
8   Q9  123 124 125 126 127
9   Q10 56  56  56  56  56
10  Q11 76  77  78  79  80
11  Q12 87  87  87  87  87
12  Q13 90  90  90  90  90
13  Q14 43  44  45  46  47
14  Q15 23  24  25  26  27
15  Q16 51  52  53  54  55
16  Q17 67  67  67  67  67
17  Q18 87  87  87  87  87
18  Q19 90  91  92  93  94
19  Q20 23  24  25  26  27
```

Now,I have applied qcut to column 'T1' to get bins by using -

```
pd.qcut(data_data['T1'].rank(method = 'first'),10,labels = list(range(1,11)))
```

that gives me.

```
0      9
1      1
2     10
3      1
4      4
5      9
6      2
7      3
8     10
9      5
10     6
11     7
12     8
13     4
14     2
15     5
16     6
17     7
18     8
19     3
```

Now, I want to get the mean of all bin 5 values, so that I can add another column in dataframe1 named 'T1_FOLD' that is simply the ((individual 'T1' values) - (that mean of bin 5 values)).

How can I do that??

Comment: Can you add expected output, first 5 rows?

Comment: Bins corresponding to index 9 and 15 is bin number 5, the values corresponding to bin 5  for column 'T1' is thus 56 and 51, so the mean is ((56+51)/2) = 53.5, so the row values of 'T1_FOLD' should be (100-53.5) = 46.5, (23-53.5) = -30.5, (345 -53.5) = 291.5 and so on.

Comment: `and so on.` means for `T1 to T5` ?

Comment: so on means that for all the rows of 'T1' column only, therefore the final dataframe that I want is the same as dataframe1 along with an additional column named 'T1_FOLD' that depends on the 'T1' column and mean of bin5 values of 'T1' column.

Answer (score 0):

Filter column `T1` with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), get `mean`s and use for subtracting of column `T1`:

```
s = pd.qcut(data_data['T1'].rank(method = 'first'),10,labels = list(range(1,11)))

data_data['T1_FOLD'] = data_data['T1'] - data_data.loc[s == 5, 'T1'].mean()
print (data_data)
     ID   T1   T2   T3   T4   T5  T1_FOLD
0    Q1  100  121   43   56   78     46.5
1    Q2   23   43   56   76   87    -30.5
2    Q3  345   56   76   78   98    291.5
3    Q4   21   32   34   45   56    -32.5
4    Q5   45  654  567   78   90     -8.5
5    Q6  123   32   45   56   67     69.5
6    Q7   23   24   25   26   27    -30.5
7    Q8   32   33   34   35   36    -21.5
8    Q9  123  124  125  126  127     69.5
9   Q10   56   56   56   56   56      2.5
10  Q11   76   77   78   79   80     22.5
11  Q12   87   87   87   87   87     33.5
12  Q13   90   90   90   90   90     36.5
13  Q14   43   44   45   46   47    -10.5
14  Q15   23   24   25   26   27    -30.5
15  Q16   51   52   53   54   55     -2.5
16  Q17   67   67   67   67   67     13.5
17  Q18   87   87   87   87   87     33.5
18  Q19   90   91   92   93   94     36.5
19  Q20   23   24   25   26   27    -30.5
```